# Why isn't this regex working in my Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to write a Python program that distinguishes between first, last, and middle names. I am using regular expressions to do it, the problematic code is below.

The issue is that the last name is picking up the middle name, I thought using a capital S at the end would make it so it only picks the word with a space before but not after it, to find the last name but the `lastNameRegex` is just picking up the middle name.

Also, the code is meant to take a name like 'John Joseph Smith' and separate each name, hence the '\w+' for first name and '\s\w*\s' for last name.

Thanks for all help, and I'm pretty new to all this stuff so all constructive criticism is welcome. Thanks! :)

```
firstNameRegex = re.compile(r'\w+')
middleNameRegex = re.compile(r'\s\w*\s')
lastNameRegex = re.compile(r'\s\w+\S')
```

Comment: Your regular expressions aren't anchored, so they'll match anywhere in the string.

Comment: Why shouldn't the last name regexp also match the middle name? `\s` matches the space, `\w+` matches `Josep`, and `\S` matches `h`.

Comment: Where is the code that uses your regex? Give an example of input followed by the output produced by the code, and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

You should anchor the regular expressions if you want them to match only at specific places in the string.  `^` matches the beginning of the string, `$` matches the end.

```
firstNameRegex = re.compile(r'^\w+')
middleNameRegex = re.compile(r'(?<=\s)\w*(?=\s)')
lastNameRegex = re.compile(r'\w+$')
```

I've also used [lookbehind and lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in `middleNameRegex` so that the spaces won't be included in the result, just the name itself.